# Отправка параметров и файла на сервер POST-запросом

Tags: java, android, post

Нужно отправить POST-запрос, содержащий несколько параметров и файл.

```
String sendfile (String filename, String filepath) throws IOException {
    String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    URL url = new URL("...");
    File file = new File(filepath);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, charset), true);

    writer.println("--" + boundary);
    writer.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key\"");
    writer.println();
    writer.println(key);

    writer.println("--" + boundary);
    writer.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"client_id\"");
    writer.println();
    writer.println(client_id);

    writer.println("--" + boundary);
    writer.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"direction_id\"");
    writer.println();
    writer.println(direction_id);

    writer.println("--" + boundary);
    writer.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"client_files\"; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
    writer.println("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    writer.println();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) writer.println(line);
    writer.println("--" + boundary + "--");
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
    return in.readLine();
}
```

Проблема где-то в последнем блоке, так как параметры сервер видит, но отвечает, что файл не найден. Пробовал закомментировать блок отправки одного параметра, но пришла ошибка авторизации.

Ошибок код не выдает.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для построения multipart/form-data лучше воспользоватся уже готовым `MultipartEntityBuilder` из пакета `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime`:

```java
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

builder.addTextBody("key", key);
builder.addTextBody("client_id", client_id );
builder.addTextBody("direction_id", direction_id);

ContentType fileContentType = ContentType.create("image/jpeg");
String fileName = file.getName();
builder.addBinaryBody("client_files", file, fileContentType, fileName);

HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
```

На написание и поддержку такого кода требуется меньше трудозатрат, да и вероятность наличия незаметной ошибки в нем тоже гораздо меньше.

Полученный HttpEntity можно записать в любой OutputStream:

```java
entity.writeTo(outputStream);
```

А ещё лучше - сразу отправить POST-запросом на сервер с помощью `HttpClient`'а из `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient`:

```java
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
request.setEntity(entity);

HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
client.execute(request);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)